# Difference between \*.xml and *.xml in find command

Tags: linux, find

What is the difference between `\*.xml` and `*.xml` in find command in Linux/mac

The results of:

`find . -name \*.xml and find . -name *.xml` are different. But why?

Also, is `locate '*.xml'` better than find? Which one is the most commonly used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By escaping the asterisk, you're giving `find` the literal string `*.xml` to match, which it could parse as a wildcard internally regardless of shell.  If you fail to escape or quote the asterisk, it will be expanded by the shell before being touched by the `find` command at all.

For example, if you only had one file `somefile.xml` in your directory, the shell would expand the wildcard and pass the literal string `somefile.xml` to your command.  ie:

```
sh-4.1$ find . -name *.xml
```

would be exactly equivalent to:

```
sh-4.1$ find . -name somefile.xml
```

which would only match that exact filename.  If you have two files in your directory which match the `*.xml` wildcard, you would probably get a syntax error when the wildcard's expanded:

```
sh-4.1$ find . -name somefile.xml someotherfile.xml
find: paths must precede expression: someotherfile.xml
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

---

As to whether or not `locate` is better, that really depends on what you're using it for.  Although `locate` is much faster, it relies on a pre-built index so it's only as good as the most recent index update (usually done daily, but that's distro-dependent).  Also, it only returns results based on filename matches, whereas `find` allows a plethora of options to refine your search.